# Android Maps Places Api with Direction Api

Tags: android, google-places-api

i am using google places api in android but i also want to find the distance between my current location to particular location shown on map please help me to find that . Because when i using direction api after getting location value from places api it takes too much time and not showing the result easily Please Please help me

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/ please refer this link, hope it would be useful to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

try this method :

```
public double CalculationsByDistance(){

    // earth radius
    int Radius = 6371;

    // set your original and destination latitude longitude
    double lat1 = new_lat; 
    double lat2 = dest_lat;
    double lon1 = new_long;
    double lon2 = dest_long;

    double d_lat = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
    double d_lon = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
    double a = Math.sin(d_lat / 2) * Math.sin(d_lat / 2) + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) * Math.sin(d_lon / 2) * Math.sin(d_lon / 2);
    double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
    hasil = Radius * c;
    double kilo_meter = hasil / 1;
    DecimalFormat formatBaru = new DecimalFormat("####");
    int kilometer_dlm_desimal = Integer.valueOf(formatBaru.format(kilo_meter));
    e = new Integer(kilometer_dlm_desimal).toString();
    double meter = hasil * 1000;
    int meter_dlm_decimal = Integer.valueOf(formatBaru.format(meter));
    d = new Integer(meter_dlm_decimal).toString();
    Log.i("Radius ", "" + hasil + " KM " + kilometer_dlm_desimal + " Meter " + meter_dlm_decimal);

    return Radius * c;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to calculate distance between two locations.
This will return approximate distance in meters.

Please pass the source and destination locations to this method.

```
private double calculateDistance(Location source, Location destination){
    double distance = 0;
    try {           


        distance = source.distanceTo(destination);
        return distance;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 0;
    }
}
```